# iPhone 6 on iOS 8.4 doesn't sent correct DTMF tones

Tags: ios, iphone

Since about July my iPhone6 on ios 8.4 does not send the correct dtmf tones to my work voicemail.

I've tried the following suggestions I found on the web, none of which have worked:

- Turn off LTE for voice
- Turn off LTE entirely
- Don't use speaker phone
- List item
- Turn off Wi-Fi
- Reset All settings

Comment: who's LTE is it

Comment: The iPhone carrier is ATT